# Detect level of input audio?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, audio-recording, microphone

I have an application which requires to use the microphone for recording user voice. I'm trying to make a `speech to text`.

I'm work with `SpeechKit.framework` and below is my code used:

```
-(void)starRecording{

  self.voiceSearch = [[SKRecognizer alloc] initWithType:SKSearchRecognizerType
                                           detection:SKShortEndOfSpeechDetection
                                           language:[[USER_DEFAULT valueForKey:LANGUAGE_SPEECH_DIC] valueForKey:@"record"]
                                           delegate:self];
}

- (void)recognizer:(SKRecognizer *)recognizer didFinishWithResults:(SKRecognition *)results {
        long numOfResults = [results.results count];

        if (numOfResults > 0) {
            // update the text of text field with best result from SpeechKit
            self.recordString = [results firstResult];
            [self sendChatWithMediaType:@"messageCall" MediaUrl:@"" ContactDetail:@"{}" LocationDetail:@"{}"];

            [self.voiceSearch stopRecording];
        }


        if (self.voiceSearch) {
            [self.voiceSearch cancel];
        }
        [self starRecording];
    }
```

That makes the `SKRecognizer` to be always open and that thing reduce the application performance.

I want to start the `SKRecognizer` when the microphone is detecting input audio.

I have a method for that? A method which is called when the microphone have input sound for me or a method which is always returning the level of audio detected?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using AvsudioRecorder class for recording audio ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the SpeechKit class to set up the audio. 
Look here for details;

http://www.raywenderlich.com/60870/building-ios-app-like-siri

This project shows how to detect audio threshold;

github.com/picciano/iOS-Audio-Recoginzer

Comment: I see already this tutorial and nothing which can help me. Is not a method which tells me when i can start recording. Is a button action there.

Comment: I see that the example works on the idea of holding a button to speak which is not your requirement. I'll edit my answer but,...
Here is a project which does what you want; https://github.com/picciano/iOS-Audio-Recoginzer

Comment: I check this file to before. I solved already. I use a 'AVAudioRecorder' to record for check average microphone power continuously.